# Group different Matrices together - cellarray

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

I was wondering what is the best way to group different matrices together.

I have multiple matrices called `A1` (of size 9 x 48), `A2` (of size 3 x 48), A3, A4 and so on.  Each of these matrices are of a different size.

I want to group all of these together so that I can easily call them in another function that iterates through each matrix.  Something like: `Group = {A1, A2, A3, A4}`

Therefore, I can run a function which calls each matrix and runs a test on it then goes to the next.

Would the best way to do this be a cell array?

Comment: Yes I would say that cell arrays are the way to go.  After that, use `cellfun` so you can process each cell and apply your test.

Comment: How would you go about putting the matrices in a cellarray if its an undetermined amount?

Comment: That's pretty simple.  Start with an empty cell array like `A = {};`.  After, simply concatenate with as many matrices as you want.  You can do something like this as an example: `A = [A rand(2)]; A = [A rand(3) rand(5)];`  This performs two separate concatenate operations.  After the end of these two, you will have a three element cell array of random matrices.  Just keep appending via `A = [A ...]` until you want to stop.

Comment: Try this - `A = [{A1},{A2},{A3},{A4}]; out = cellfun(@your_function_name ,A,'uni',0);`. Please note that you need to put the other input parameters to the function through `cellfun` and also that `out` would be a cell array though. If `cellfun` looks like a tedious task, you can use a for-loop rather like this - `for k = 1:numel(A),out = your_function_name(A{k},param2,param3);end`.

Comment: You can also grow a cell matrix like this: `Group(end+1) = An` assuming that `Group` is already a cell array